# Not getting "Import Module" option in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to import one external existing module to my android application. My Android Studio version is 3.0.1. But I am not getting any import module option by clicking the file in Android Studio. So, how can I import the module in my application?

[image]

Comment: Hi Asif, click File >> New >> Import Module instead of right click on your project. More details: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module

Answer (score 0):

Yon can import module by clicking on

> file>new>import module

OR do it by following

1. place the module folder in the root directory of your project.
2. open setting.gradle file and include it in this file like

> "include 'your module folder name'"

Thats all now the module is added in your android studio project and you can access its methods with in your project.